# Piecewise continuous function

Tags: calculus, proof-writing

[image]

I'm trying to prove this, and here what I got so far

Let f be defined on A, $a=kπ$ is cluster point of A
Part 1: if $a=kπ$ for some k∈Z then $f$ is continuous at $a$

Take ε>0, let $δ=sin^{-1}⁡(ε)$ st $0<|x-kπ|<δ$. When $x$ is a rational

$|f(x)-f(a)|=|sin⁡|x|-sin⁡|kπ||=|sin⁡〖|x||〗<ε$

Observe that

|x-kπ|<δ

Now I'm stuck. I don't know hot link the last line to the inequality above it

Comment: Use sequential criterion for continuity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider any sequence of rational numbers converging to $k\pi$, $k \in \mathbb{Z}$, say $\{x_n\}$. So $\{f(x_n)\}$ converges to $0$. Take any sequence of irrational numbers say $\{y_n\}$ converges to $k\pi$. See $\{f(y_n)\}$ converging to $0$. So $f$ is continuous at $k\pi$.

For any other points $x$ construct any two sequences of rational and irrational numbers, converging to $x$ and see if the sequential criterion holds for the function $f$.

So you may conclude that $f$ is continuous only at $k\pi$.

Comment: you mean $k∈Z$ ?